# Parsing request.request_parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a web service app and I'm trying to handle nicely a 422 page sending back to the user the JSON the POSTed to better debug the error. To do this, I use request.request_parameters which get me back the JSON I sent, but it happens to be organized (for me) in a wired way and I can't really get it back only with the original data

What I send as JSON is this.

```
{   
  "name":"New set intensity",
  "properties":
  [
    {"uri":null,"value":"on"},     
    {"uri":"https://type.lelylan.com/properties/intensity","value":"100.0"}
  ]
}
```

What I get from request.request_parameters is this.

```
{"{\"name\":\"New set intensity\",\"properties\":"=>{"{\"uri\":null,\"value\":\"on\"},  {\"uri\":\"https://type.lelylan.com/properties/intensity\",\"value\":\"100.0\"}"=>{"}"=>nil}}}
```

My main problem is that somehow the content becomes the key, and this recursively inside. Is there a way to get back the clean data? Thanks a lot.

UPDATE: I'm trying to better understand where and why this problem occurs.

In my controller I tried to access in the two available ways I know.

```
# request.body.read.inspect
"{\"name\":\"New set intensity\",\"properties\":[{\"uri\":\"not_valid\"}]}"                                                                                                                                     

# request.request_parameters
{"{\"name\":\"New set intensity\",\"properties\":"=>{"{\"uri\":\"not_valid\"}"=>{"}"=>nil}}}
```

The request is made from Capybara

```
page.driver.post(@uri, @params.to_json)
```

The controller returns only JSON so this is the way I defined it. I din't put 'respond_to' and 'respond_with' and when I make the request it renders the json view show.rabl.json. This makes me think that it recognize the correct format.

```
class FunctionsController < ApplicationController

before_filter
...

def index
  ...
end

def show
..
end

def create
  body = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  @function = Function.new(body)
  if @function.save
    render 'show', status: 201, location: FunctionDecorator.decorate(@function).uri
  else
    render_422 "notifications.resource.not_valid", @function.errors
  end
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: are they setting the content type when they are sending their request? Looks like rails is interpreting this as if it were a form encoded post.

Comment: By default I set the JSON format in the routing system, so if no content-type is set, the JSON one should be taken. Here a sample of the routing command  
> resources :functions, defaults: { format: 'json' }

Comment: Actually i think that's about the format of the response, not the format of the request

Comment: i guess that someone is not properly formatting input our output. how are you sending your code to the server?

Comment: The call is made using capybara as follow page.driver.post uri, params.to_json. Frederick, why do you think that the problem is about the format of the response? I'm gonna try to sort it out now.